# INSTALACION DE LIBRERIA DJANGO-CELERY ESTA IMPOSIBLE INSTALAR

Tags: python, django, pip

lo que pasa es lo siguiente es que estoy pasando un proyecto de `django` a otro computador al momento de pasar las librerías todo va bien hasta que pasa por `celery` y `django-celery` ya lei toda la documentación hice las configuraciones que ahí indica, ya actualicé todo y todavía me sigue saliendo este error:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las versiones de `Python` y de `pip` que tienes instaladas en la otra máquina y en la actual?

Comment: python3.6 y aca instalado el 3.12

Comment: clarooo no me fije en esoo hace rato no tocaba el proyecto y esta diseñado con python 3.6 eres un genioooo graciass fx

Comment: En la parte inferior agrega la respuesta detallando los pasos que hiciste para solucionar tu caso, serás el héroe de más usuarios que les ocurra lo mismo o algo similar. Éxitos con el desarrollo y gracias por el halago :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno lo que pasa es que la librería que estaba intentando instalar. la estaba intentando instalar a la fuerza con versiones que no son compatibles tanto la librería (django-celery) como el Python 3.12 entonces una vez identificado eso me puse a leer la documentación y la respuesta estaba clara, aca les dejo el link de esa documentación en específico https://pypi.org/project/django-celery/ (la respuesta es que no son compatibles los dos y por eso me generaba el error entonces instala python 3.6 y listo) aunque tienen compatibilidad hasta la version 3.9 python

Comment: Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta luego de 24 horas, de ese modo ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (efecto del porcentaje de preguntas resueltas). Gracias por la cooperación y dale con todo el power 2.0!!! :D